# Где учить laravel+vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Учу лару на протяжении полугода, понимаю, что это довольно таки мало, но всё же, хотел бы развиваться в ширь, нежели в глубь. Поэтому, начал гуглить инфу про лару в совметке с каким нибудь популярным фреймворком, наткнулся на крутой,востребованный вью, но никак не могу найти достойный ресурс, где бы можно было учить его вместе с ларой. Несомненно, есть нормальные статьи, плейлисты на ютубе, которые учат этому, НО, опять же, этого очень мало(т.е по ним, можно связать вью, сделать базовый функционал, но никак не приятный для глаз интерфейс).
Под "учить вью" я подразумеваю, ну не то чтобы жирный, но хотя бы плотный объем материала по одной и той же версии этих фреймворков(например лару 8ой версии + вью 2 версии либо же лару 9 версии и вью 3 версии)
p.s Даже неважно, платный ли будет этот плейлист/курс, но желательно, чтобы он был на русском

Comment: https://laracasts.com/browse/frameworks Вот здесь полно материалов на различные фреймворки. Изначально проект был создан как раз для лары, но постепенно было добавленно множество других уроков.

Comment: Пересматривайте подход. Laravel - это только бэкенд, смотрите как пишется API (REST, выдача JSON). Vue - это только фронт (не берем SSR в расчет, как говорится, это другое ). Т.е это 2 независимые части. И если Вы Vue замените на React/Angular/Svelte или вторую часть с Laravel на Symfony/Express.js/ASP/Drogon, не меняя первой и наоборот - ничего не изменится.
Поэтому рассматривайте 2 технологии абстрактно. Отдельно учите Laravel, отдельно Vue и не связывайте их.

Comment: Ну а так, заходите на YouTube и ищите "Vue уроки".

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar сначала, я так и хотел, но сейчас я сталкиваюсь с такими проблемами по типу "а как вызвать определенный контроллер, при отправке формы" или "а вот как объеденить джейсон ответ с одинаковыми параметрами, в один массив" я понял, что без какого либо "полноценного" вводного курса, мне не обойтись

Comment: @yellows009 Вы оперируете не контроллерами с фронта, а посылаете запрос к ссылке и получаете в ответ что-то и его обрабатываете. На бэке вызов контроллера по ссылке ровно такой же, как и в обычном Laravel. На фронте, соответственно, для вызова Fetch или Axios использовать. Опять же, как объединить json - ну, тут сначала нужно понимать, что JSON в PHP не существует, есть массивы и функции, преобразующие эти массивы в строки, которые читаются как JSON. Исходя из этого, Вы должны почитать об объединении массивов в документации PHP или об объединении коллекций в Laravel.

Comment: Т.е исходя из слов выше, Вам всё равно не нужно учить что-то в связке, а понимать, как с чем работать в отдельной части, и для этого в документациях обычно есть объяснение.

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar да, спасибо большое, теперь хоть есть общее представление о том, куда двигаться